# ClipToBounds and TranslateTransform

Tags: wpf, text, scroll

I do text smoothly moving from right to left.
for motion I use TranslateTransform.
The right part of the text that gets abroad Grid should appear when scrolling.
But it is cut off (Clip) on the right edge of the Grid. And not restored even when shifted to the left.
What should I do to clipping was not?

```
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Width="180" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Label Content="Test Text" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="72" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Label.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform/>
                    <TranslateTransform X="-60"/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Label.RenderTransform>
        </Label>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My decision.
Completely remove the `Grid` and replace it with  `Canvas`.

Reply @Erti-Chris Eelmaa brought me to the correct decision.
But it is a recommendation impossible in my case. As the position of the Grid Row does not correspond to the position in the Canvas.
`HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top`" for Label I replaced to absolute positions in the Canvas.

`TranslateTransform` I decided not to use. And use animation with changing properties Canvas.Left.

In the properties of Canvas, you must enable `ClipToBounds = "True"` for the correct clipping.

```
<Canvas  ClipToBounds="True">
       <Label x:Name="text_area" Content="Test Text"  Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" FontSize="72">
</Canvas>
```

Helper function for animation:

```
ScrollText(text_area,-60,1000,30);


            public static void ScrollText(FrameworkElement c, double to, int wait_msec, int msec_perpixel)
            {
                DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation
                {
                    AutoReverse = true,
                    BeginTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, wait_msec),
                    To = to,
                    Duration = new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, (int)Math.Abs(to) * msec_perpixel)),
                };


                c.BeginAnimation(Canvas.LeftProperty, animation);
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap Label element into Canvas,
such as:

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Width="180" VerticalAlignment="Top">
  <Canvas>
    <Label Content="Test Text" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="72" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Label.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform/>
                <TranslateTransform X="-60"/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Label.RenderTransform>
    </Label>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

This will stop any clipping occuring.